# getEval returning null on Selenium even though javascript returns value in console

Tags: javascript, selenium, getelementbyid

I am running a getEval in Selenium with the following javascript:

```
document.getElementById("j_id0:j_id3:mainBlock:j_id40").children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0] .children[2].children[0].children[0].children[0] .children[0].children[1];
```

When I run the code in the console, it returns the correct result.

When I navigate to the page on which the element I need to locate exists and click the "find" button in Selenium, it finds and highlights the correct element.  Hoever, when I actually run the line in Selenium - even when I navigate to the correct page and run ONLY that line - I get a message that says

```
[error]Threw an exception: document.getElementById(...)is null
```

How do I make this work correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Just include *this.browserbot.getUserWindow()* before your actual JS stament started and try.

```
selenium.getEval("this.browserbot.getUserWindow().document.getElementById("j_id0:j_id3:mainBlock:j_id40").children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0] .children[2].children[0].children[0].children[0] .children[0].children[1]")
```